# How can I loop Opacity change & Display state on multiple DIV tags

Tags: javascript, css, opacity, display

I have a bar at the bottom of my page (ribbon)

It has 4 `<div>` tags that start at full opacity. They are all clickable links.

There are 4 more that are in the same position, but have `display:none`

I need the 1st 4 to go from `opacity:1;` to `opacity:0;` in a stepping fashion from left to right with maybe a small time difference like 1 sec apart.

After the 1st 4 disappear I want to replace their positions with the new 4 in a similar way.  Opacity:0 to 1 from left to right about 1 sec apart.

They would stay on screen for 5 sec, and the loop would repeat itself. Timings I can tweak, I just need to understand the main nuts and bolts of the code.

So after the opacity on each `<div>` goes down to 0 the display would change to none.  And of course change back to block when to loop cycles back.

Reason I thought I needed display on/off was because they occupy the same space and are clickable links.  If there is a better way I am all ears.

```js
fadeloop('#ribbon_box_01_id', 500, 5000, true);
fadeloop('#ribbon_box_02_id', 500, 5500, true);
fadeloop('#ribbon_box_03_id', 500, 6000, true);
fadeloop('#ribbon_box_04_id', 500, 6500, true);

function fadeloop(el, timeout, timein, loop) {
  var $el = $(el),
    intId, fn = function() {
      $el.fadeTo(timeout, 0).fadeTo(timein, 1);
    };
  fn();
  if (loop) {
    intId = setInterval(fn, timeout + timein + 3000);
    return intId;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.ribbon_flex_wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 10vh;
  -moz-box-flex: 0 0 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 10vh;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 10vh;
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.ribbon_services_body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.ribbon_services_box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ribbon_films_box {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ribbon_flex_wrapper" id="ribbon_flex_wrapper_id">
  <div class="ribbon_services_body">
    <!-----------SERVICES---------------->
    <div class="ribbon_services_box" id="ribbon_box_01_id" onClick="edit();">
      <div class="ribbon_services_box" id="ribbon_box_02_id" onClick="vfx();">
        <div class="ribbon_services_box" id="ribbon_box_03_id" onClick="audio();">
          <div class="ribbon_services_box" id="ribbon_box_04_id" onClick="color();">
            <!-----------OUR FILMS--------------->
            <div class="ribbon_films_box" id="ribbon_box_05_id" onClick="xxx();">
              <div class="ribbon_films_box" id="ribbon_box_06_id" onClick="xxx();">
                <div class="ribbon_films_box" id="ribbon_box_07_id" onClick="xxx();">
                  <div class="ribbon_films_box" id="ribbon_box_01_id" onClick="xxx();">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This has a nice fade, but I don't know how I would add the display change and the other 4 tags.  Again this is just one of many starting places I found,  If you think something entirely different is better, Im open to that.

**Ribbon looks like this:**

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To try to achieve what you want, if I understand it ok, I would use simple css3 animations for the "opacity" effect.

First I would place the last 4 `divs` under the first 4 with z-index and, again, use a simple animation to change the z-index so all divs are always correctly clicked (with opacity, the hidden `div` would still stay above). I would use z-index as `display` property can't be used on animations.

Then You just need  a simple `jquery`script to add the animation classes to the `divs`.

like this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".box4").addClass("fadein");
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".box3").addClass("fadein");
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $(".box2").addClass("fadein"); 
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".box1").addClass("fadein");
                $(".banner2").addClass("zindex");
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".box5").addClass("fadeout");
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".box6").addClass("fadeout");
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".box7").addClass("fadeout");
                            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                $(".box8").addClass("fadeout");
                            }, 1000);
                        }, 1000);
                    }, 1000);
                }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body, div {margin:0; padding:0}
img {display:block;}
.container {
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-left:-5px;
}
.banner1, .banner2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
.banner1 {
  z-index:5
}
.banner2 {
  z-index:1;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {}
.box5, .box6, .box7, .box8 {opacity:0;}
.fadein {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fadeout {
  animation-name: fadeout;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.zindex {
  animation-name: zindex ;
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  0% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
  0% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes zindex {
  0% {z-index:1; }
  100% {z-index:10; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="banner1">
<div class="box box1"><img src="https://t00.deviantart.net/OHnECGm-qAA6y-TCecwbQV9nQlY=/fit-in/150x150/filters:no_upscale():origin()/pre00/203f/th/pre/f/2018/036/c/6/mission_impossible_6_by_queenofnightwish-dc298a8.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box2"><img src="https://t05.deviantart.net/K9H6kV3KW6NCFUOu9J8bNr6DKGY=/fit-in/150x150/filters:no_upscale():origin()/pre00/b405/th/pre/f/2009/174/0/6/bruce_lee_signature_by_stfx_art.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box3"><img src="https://t00.deviantart.net/yQx2SZhR-zq-1zLFnerYPlMVL3U=/fit-in/150x150/filters:no_upscale():origin()/pre00/0519/th/pre/f/2009/123/f/6/gambit_by_modestroad.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box4"><img src="https://t00.deviantart.net/Ptw-vGWCgr6_q7b54nRrY3EZ7ic=/fit-in/150x150/filters:no_upscale():origin()/pre00/a85b/th/pre/i/2016/217/0/d/shah_rukh_khan_by_rizucreation-dacsd72.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
<div class="banner2">
<div class="box box5"><img src="https://image.redbull.com/rbcom/010/2012-05-19/1331574558762_1/0010/1/150/50/1/jenny-rissveds-podium.JPG" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box6"><img src="https://image.redbull.com/rbcom/052/2018-07-05/550b8e50-8419-4b31-90b4-8450ec7f83e8/0012/0/262/0/1329/3200/150/1/f1-2018-max-verstappen.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box7"><img src="https://image.redbull.com/rbcom/010/2014-05-26/1331654253313_9/0010/1/150/50/1/imagen-de-vi%C3%B1ales-y-salom-en-la-pretemporada.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="box box8"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOPaBgzYMm41trhcBkJ0B1-QaQ46EzX6ZQ864lloFBBAYWiqo_tg" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
<button>start</button>
```

btw, I have used a buttom to trigger the effect. Apologise for the ugly looking nested timeouts, not much time left to tidy it up.